# Gmap click marker should zoom the map and display other markers

Tags: 7, views, google-maps

I have two content types: **City** and **Place**.
Both of them use a `location` field which has lat long fields enabled.

The *Place* content type has a node reference field to *City* content type.

I want to display a google map, which will display the *City* nodes markers. Clicking on any marker will zoom the map and will display the place nodes markers in that city.

And then clicking the place marker which will open its detail page.

Is it possible with gmap and views or any other module? Or a custom script will be used?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).
>
> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).
>
> And the [Set my location](http://regionbound.com/coffee-prices-across-melbourne) block allows your visitors to locate themselves on the map, either automagically --via the Wifi/GPS device on their mobile-- or by typing an address or landmark, like "Eiffel tower" (bottom screenshot, upper left corner, click to enlarge).
>
> Follow this step-by-step tutorial to create a handy [store locator with proximity search, from a list of addresses in a spreadsheet](http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-mapping-with-leaflet-and-ipgeoloc). You'll learn about the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) modules too!
>
> Finally IPGV&M provides a set of visitor location retrieval technologies, both IP and HTML5-based, so that you can track where past visits came from and where current visitors are located, superimposing their moving positions as markers on your maps.

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it.

Comment: I can't see any option for displaying only city markers and clicking on that marker will zoom the map to display place makers in this module.